# When querying SQL with EF6 from a WebJob, query fails because it's trying to get a pluralized version of the table

Tags: entity-framework-6, webjob

My code looks like this:

```
public static void DoSomething(TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine("Hey man! I'm running!");

            try
            {
                using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
                {
                    MemberMaster mm = context.MemberMaster.SingleOrDefault(m => m.MemberMasterId == 1);

                    if (mm != null)
                    {
                        log.WriteLine(string.Format("MemberMasterId = {0}, Username = {1}", mm.MemberMasterId, mm.UserName));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.WriteLine("Could not find Member with MembermasterId = 1");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            log.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
```

MyDBContext.cs looks like this:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() : this("MyDb")
    {

    }

    public MyDBContext(string connectionName) : base(connectionName) { }

    public DbSet<MemberMaster> MemberMaster { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to add a modelBuilder to remove Pluralizing names but that simply results in an error about the DB Context having changed....use code first...etc..etc...

Is there a better way to do this? The WebJob is being deployed via AZure with a .ZIP file and resides in the same AppService as my Website.

Answer (score 0):

I turn off plurallizing on Sets and Tables by overriding the OnModelCreating, to keep both named the same, and have had no problem:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDBContext() : this("MyDb")
    {

    }

    public MyDBContext(string connectionName) : base(connectionName) { }

    public DbSet<MemberMaster> MemberMaster { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: As indicated in the original post, I've tried to do this but end up with an EF error about Code First Migrations (i.e. the underlying model has changed etc....consider using code first migrations...etc...) There are no changes. I just want to talk to the table. How to get around this 'error' ?

Comment: Ok, assuming you do not want changes to your model to affect your database, try adding the static constructor above to disable migrations. This is more a database first approach.